# URL Variables in a Certain Page

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a product loop in a certain page,
and I want to filter its categories via URL such as:

```
mysite.com/products // Shows all products
mysite.com/products/sculptures // Shows only sculptures
mysite.com/products/sculptures/2 // Shows only sculptures paged 2
mysite.com/products/paintings // Shows only paintings
```

So I am trying to map like this:

```
mysite.com/products/{category}/{paged} // Shows only sculptures
```

But this hasn't worked so far. By the way, my code also works as shortcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );
function my_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'catname';
    return $vars;
}

add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_rewrite_rules' );
function my_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite )
{
    $products_page_id = 1; //your product's page ID
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array(
        'products/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?page_id='.$products_page_id.'&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ),
        'products/(.+?)/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?page_id='.$products_page_id.'&catname='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ).'&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 2 ),
        'products/(.+?)/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?page_id='.$products_page_id.'&catname='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ),
    ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

You'll get cat_name than as `get_query_var('catname');` and paged as `get_query_var('paged');`

To little explain the code above: this adds rewrite rules to WordPress, when each request to www.yourdomain.com/products/ get rewrote to (means brings content from) www.yourdomain.com/index.php?page_id={$products_page_id}&paged=2 (for example).

$producst_page_id is a ID of your products page in administration with your shorcode - thus page which content should appear. paged is a parameter for you to be able to get another page of your products. catname is another param for you to, filter returned products by category.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems the page name must be "static", right? How can I make it dynamic?

Comment: I'v modified the code to use with page_id instead of pagename

Comment: @david-binda Then we still need to put "products" into rewrite rules?

Comment: yes, you have...

Comment: @david-binda I see, then what does "products_page_id" work for?

Comment: see modified answer above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7393/discussion-between-digerkam-and-david-binda)